# Unrecognized selector sent to instance ('NSInvalidArgumentException')

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm setting up a class to view video using Google VR. It runs without error using the sample code. When I copy the class and view controller over to my project, this error occurs:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109d04d90'

Here's the relevant code:

```
  @interface VideoPlayerViewController () <GVRVideoViewDelegate>
  @property(nonatomic) IBOutlet GVRVideoView *videoView;
  @property(nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *attributionTextView;
  @end

  _videoView.delegate = self;
  _videoView.enableFullscreenButton = YES;
  _videoView.enableCardboardButton = YES;
  _videoView.enableTouchTracking = YES;
```

I can't figure out why it works in one instance and not the other. Everything is connected up in the storyboard.

This is driving me crazy. Please help!

Comment: You are assigning a `UIView`, not a `GVRVideoView` to your `videoView` outlet.

Comment: Have you set GVRVideoView class in your view's class in storyboard? can you please post some more code of your GVRVideoView class?

Comment: Yes, it's a UIView custom class of type GVRVideoView connected to the IBOutlet videoView.

Comment: No, you have not assigned a `GVRVideoView` to the outlet. You have assigned a plain `UIView`. That is what the error is telling you.

Comment: Please explain.

Comment: @HolpMike open storyboard and check whether the `Custom Class` of this view set to `GVRVideoView` in inspector

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

Open storyboard in Scrollview choose the video view and then Choose the Custom class.Then give the class name as GVRVideoView.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the visual feedback. I copied the code and viewcontroller from the sample code. It still doesn't work. Same error.